# Copy Bash profile from remote system up to a certain line number point

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to copy a file from a remote machine onto my local machine, up to the first line containing a certain pattern.

Scenario: update my local Bash profile with a part of the remote Bash profile, up to the point in which my admin has verified it.

Is there a better way (I guess there likely is!) than this quick "shell scripting" hack?

```
ssh tinosino@robottinosino-wifi cat /Users/tinosino/.profile | sed '/Verify this script further than this point/,$ d' > /home/tinosino/Desktop/tinosino_bash_profile.sh
```

- Remote machine: robottinosino-wifi (OSX)
- Sentinel line: Verify this script further than this point

I can use basic shell scripting, preferably in Bash as it's the default, or the most common diff/source-control bins..

The idea, you guess it, is to ultimately automate this process. Cron? Any idea as to how you would do this? The start of my Bash profile should come from the server, the "rest" is free for me to customise.

Prev failed attempts of mine:

- using `head`
- using process substituion `<( ... )`
- using `grep`
- using a local named pipe (this was fun: the named pipe needs a program generating its text though, executing something like the cat->sed line above)

**Important note**: what would be *highly desirable* is for the remote system **not** to go through the entire file, but to *truncate* the filter once it "sees" the sentinel line.. If pattern is in line #300 of 1,000,000,000.. just go over 300 lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your sed command is structured to read through the entire file.

You can use `sed -n '/Verify this script/q; p'` to instead quit once the line is found:

```
ssh tinosino@robottinosino-wifi cat /Users/tinosino/.profile | sed -n '/Verify this script/q; p' > /home/tinosino/Desktop/tinosino_bash_profile.sh
```

Or without the [useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html), which doesn't make a significant difference in this case, but which will transfer less data if you want to remove multiple sections later:

```
ssh tinosino@robottinosino-wifi "sed -n '/Verify this script/q; p' /Users/tinosino/.profile" > /home/tinosino/Desktop/tinosino_bash_profile.sh
```

Comment: This is pure awesomeness. I just love the `-n` + `; p` combo which even leaves out the sentinel line! Thanks! (btw I am not so hung up on the useless use of cat in general..)

Comment: For others copying and pasting this into their terminals, BTW, one should probably backslash escape both the single quotes and the semicolon.

Comment: Do you have any examples for when escaping the single quotes and semicolons would be a good idea?

Comment: On my machine, if I don't escape, your one-liner does not run? Does it run on yours?

Comment: Good disciple fixing it for others! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just perform the filtering on the remote server.

```
ssh tinosino@robottinosino-wifi sed -n 'p;/Verify.../q' /Users/tinosino/.profile \
  >>/home/tinosino/Desktop/tinosino_bash_profile.sh
```

The `-n` flag and the `p` and `q` commands together print only the lines up to, but not including, the first line that starts with "Verify...".

Comment: He absolutely did :) Besides, mine is only more compact because I was too lazy to type out (or even cut-and-paste) the sentinel. The fact that my `...` is even valid is coincidental to it being a valid regular expression.